# Python crazy module import in a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I'm inside a python package where there is A.py, B.py and an init file that allows me to import packages into the directory above.

Thus, the content of my init file is as follows:

```
__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

I now want to import a class of B.py into A.py. I tried to use `from B import myClass` but it doesn't work. I also tried to add the file in the path by adding this line to the init file :

```
__path__.append(__file__)
```

How to add B.py to the path ?

--edit--

To clarify things, here is the structure of my packages and modules :

```
|app.py 
|package1
    |__init__.py
    |C.py
    |package2
        |__init__.py
        |A.py
        |B.py
```

In A.py I need to import classes from B.py and C.py

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the layout of your files? What do you mean by "import packages into the directory above"? It is not entirely clear  what you are trying to do. Is there a reason why you don't use relative imports, i.e. ``from .B import myClass`` (note the ``.``)?

Comment: I just edited my question. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, that makes it clearer indeed. Can you still please clarify why you don't use relative imports, such as ``from .B import myClass`` and ``from ..C import myClass``?

Comment: Yes, it's working with `from .B import myClass`

Answer (score 0):

If this is python 3 related code...then *really* there's no need for an `__init__.py` anymore.

As long as your files that you want to import classes/functions from are within the same directory you should be able to just call in the file you want to do the import as this:

```
 import B.myClass
```

or,

```
 from . import myClass
 ### this imports all the classes and moduels from within the same directory 
 ### as you're currently in even if it has more than one file (but only imports myClass)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have an error : `cannot import name myClass from B (my_path/__init__.py)` I need to import another class from a package above as well so I can't remove my __init__.py